# Android studio : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I'm getting a gradle error at building since

Full error here:

My project depends on multiple libraries

[image: Andriod studio : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.]

**build.gradle (module :app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.haja.ballpoolCheats"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile files('libs/calligraphy-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

**build.gradle (projet)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**How can I fix this error?**

Answer (score 1):

Change the min sdk version to 9, google play services support version above 8 or **Froyo** i.e from sdk version 9. If you want support for
**Froyo** also there is separate supprt library for that i  think no body in the world are not using the Froyo. Better don't worry about that just mention min sdk version 9

Answer (score 0):

The compilesdk version and version of the library must be the same..
Please check how to change the compile SDK version or download the latest library of version same as the compilesdk version